# Which way is right for "Strong Reference Cycles for Closures"

Tags: swift

In [Apple Swift Document](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

> A strong reference cycle can also occur if you assign a closure to a property of a class instance, and the body of that closure captures the instance.

The reCreactJavascriptTool is a property of a Controller which contains a WKWebview.   The main work of the reCreactJavascriptTool is reacting with the HTML file.

```
private lazy var reCreactJavascriptTool: JavascriptTool = {
var reCreactJSTool = JavascriptTool()

reCreactJSTool.reJSBlock = { [unowned self] (module: String?, hareModel: HareModel?) in

    if module == "hare" {
        self.XXXcode
    }

}

reCreactJSTool.bBlock = { [unowned self] (btnId: String?) in
            self.lefckId = btnId;
    self.confS()
}


reCreactJSTool.reBlock = { [unowned self] in

    if (self.recordUrl?.absoluteString.count)! > 0 {
               XXXXXXcode           
    }else {
        
          XXXXXXcode 
         XXXXXXcode
    }

}

return reCreactJSTool
}()
```

If I type the code like this :

```
    private lazy var reCreactJavascriptTool: JavascriptTool = {  [unowned self]  in 
               
                // And remove all the " [unowned self] " in  all Blocks
               

         reCreactJSTool.reJSBlock = { (module: String?, hareModel: HareModel?) in

          if module == "hare" {
             self.XXXcode
          }

       }

  reCreactJSTool.bBlock = {  (btnId: String?) in
         self.lefckId = btnId;
        self.confS()
      }


   reCreactJSTool.reBlock = {  in

        if (self.recordUrl?.absoluteString.count)! > 0 {
            XXXXXXcode           
       }else {

          XXXXXXcode 
          XXXXXXcode
          }

           }


      }
```

I don't know which code snippet is right.

Comment: The second way is sufficient. You have made self unowned everywhere in the anonymous function. But is this really a good idea? If self goes out of existence you will crash.

Comment: @matt   The " reCreactJavascriptTool"  is a property of A  Controller Contained wkWebView. Because of this, in my opinion, self, the controller, will never die in the lifeTime of reCreactJavascriptTool.